# Hibernate: Entity property from non-entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

so I have an hibernate Entity called Appointment, in this entity I have a AppointNumber property which itself contains a number property which is a string.
When I persist my Appointment, I need the AppointmentNumber. I got it to work with @Embedded and @Embeddable the other day but this creates a join table Which I can't have.
I tried many other solutions to try and get it to work without join tables but I can't figure it out. (I get lots of ava.lang.IllegalStateException)
Can anyone help?
Thanks!

```
@Entity(name = "appointments")
public class Appointment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "number")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    private AppointmentNumber appointmentNumber;
```

[Appointment entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXnJe.png)

[AppointmentNumber, used in Appointment but should not be an entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps5aW.png)

```
public class AppointmentNumber {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "appointmentNumber", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String number;
```

Comment: Please add your code as text.

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
@Entity(name = "appointments")
public class Appointment {

  ///....
  @Convert(converter = AppointmentNumberConverter.class)
  private AppointmentNumber appointmentNumber;
  ///....
}


@Converter
public class AppointmentNumberConverter implements 
AttributeConverter<PersonName, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(AppointmentNumber appointmentNumber) {
    if (appointmentNumber == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return appointmentNumber.getNumber();
  }

  @Override
  public AppointmentNumber convertToEntityAttribute(String appointmentNumber) {
    if (appointmentNumber == null) {
        return null;
    }
    AppointmentNumber result = new AppointmentNumber();
    result.setNumber(appointmentNumber);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Have a look at JPA Converter documentation.

Comment: That is the first thing I tried but for some reason I still get a java.IllegalStateExpression error that makes my app crash.

Comment: actually I just had to change this: @Converter(autoApply=true) and the java exceptions is no more!
Now I just have this error: "Parameter value [2020-11-22-Jon Doe] did not match expected type [ca.ulaval.glo4002.garage.domain.appointments.AppointmentNumber" when I try to find my Appointment with the appointment number (using this query: em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM appointments a WHERE a.appointmentNumber = :number").setParameter("number", number);
any idea?

Comment: 1)@Column(name = "number") in entity; 2) em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM appointments a WHERE a.number = :number").setParameter("number", "123"); . Try this